# ros commands not found in qt

Tags: c++, qt, ros

I am facing an error when I tried to run ROS commands from qtquick appliction using system function in c++. Where as when i run some other simple cpp file consisting

```
system("roscore")
```

it did work .
But when i ran same function in qt app,

I got the following error

```
sh: 1: roscore: not found
```

So can anyone tell me what to do??

Edit : Link to code on [github](https://github.com/abhisaini/AUV-Qt-Interface/tree/BackEnd/Random-Tries/try-1)

Comment: Please, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Moreover, [do not post errors as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Are your running the qt program from a terminal where  `roscore` works?

Comment: no i am not running qt programme from terminal...i am running it from editor

Comment: It looks like i need to add some path to include commands, but i dont know how.

Comment: Run it from the terminal to see if it is an environment problem. You probably do not have loaded in QtCreator all the paths and definitions that ROS needs. For further information on how to use QtCreator and ROS please visit: http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#QtCreator

Comment: actually i cant even create files from qt if I try system("touch something") , So maybe I need permissions??

Comment: Can you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: the link you told me tell that how to open packages n all in ros...it didnt told me how to include ros commands in qt programm

Comment: No, the [link](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#QtCreator) that I gave you explains how to properly set up QtCreator IDE so it is not launched form the terminal: _As QtCreator supports opening CMake projects out of the box, it does not require a setup procedure it does not require a setup procedure if started from a terminal. Note that this is absolutely crucial, because otherwise the environment will not be set correctly and functionality related to rosbuild or catkin will fail when running cmake._

Comment: ya i got what you told me...but my project dont run on cmake it runs on qmake
Well I am posting the link to code

Comment: If you load QtCreator properly, as explained in the [link](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#QtCreator) I gave you. QtCreator will be loaded with all the ROS environment and your problem will most likely be solved. What they explain in the link has nothing to do with CMake but with loading the ROS environment into QtCreator.

Comment: I think u wanted me to do a small edit in qtcreator.desktop file , Well I did that and there was no improvement.

Comment: I tried to run my app from terminal then I got the error  <QApplication> not found. Simply the terminal cant reach the library but no such error occur when I run the app from Qt Creator.
So do u know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I Don't Think Adding `QML_IMPORT_PATH = /opt/ros/kinetic/bin` Is Enough.

You Need To Source setup.bash first cause qt Console Don't Use `.bashrc` Environments.

Simplest Way Is To Source setup.bash At The Start Of Your Code Before Calling Any ros-based commands

EDIT1:

You can call Absolute Path To Your Executable for instance `roscore` will be `/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/roscore`

Comment: I didnt got it...can u explain in some detail?

Comment: call system("source /opt/ros/<Your DISTRO>/setup.bash") before using any ros-commands in your code. this should add Paths To The Console

Comment: When I tired this
It says source not found

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19409940/how-to-get-output-system-command-in-qt/19413789 This Might Help You

Answer (score 0):

Just launch the Qt Creator app from the terminal and everything will work fine!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33444631)